# Add border to circle image

Tags: border, css

I've added a normal square image to my website and made it into a circle with border-radius and then have tried to add a circle border around it but it only seems to work on Chrome. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
.face {
display: block;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 5px solid #ff675b;}
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xy26phkjgz9te0/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-01%20at%2001.15.02.png

Answer (score 25):

See this JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/z3rLa/1/

```
.avatar {
    width:128px;
    margin: 10px;
    border:10px solid red;
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That is the way I use:

CSS:

```
.avatar {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border: 5px solid #cfd8dc;
}

img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="avatar" src="..">
```

Answer (score 5):

create a new class:

```
.circleborder {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 150px;
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
background: url(URL) no-repeat;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

and this would be your html code:

```
<div class="circleborder"><img src="URL"/></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML:

```
<div class="circleborder"><img class="face" src="img/face.jpeg" alt="face" width="130" height="130"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.face {
border-radius: 100%;}

.circleborder {
border: 5px solid #ff675b;
border-radius: 100%;
display: inline-block;}
```

Thanks for your help guys! I'm testing my solution as we speak and sofar it's worked on Chrome & Safari on my Mac and iPhone! :D

Answer (score 1):

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Border radius doesn't work the same way in every browser. You need different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will be help for you.

```
.clip-circle {
      clip-path: circle(60px at center);
      /* OLD VALUE example: circle(245px, 140px, 50px); */
      /* Yep, even the new clip-path has deprecated stuff. */
    }
    .clip-ellipse {
      clip-path: ellipse(60px 40px at 75px 30px);
      /* OLD VALUE example: ellipse(245px, 80px, 75px, 30px); */
    }
    .clip-polygon {
      clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 75% 75%, 75% 100%, 50% 75%, 0% 75%);
      /* Note that percentages work as well as px */
    }
```